# How to turn off programmatically "Volume Limit" from Settings->Music

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-audio

I do some FFT on audio data coming from iOS microphone.
I'm able to turn off low frequency filter by setting AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement mode:

`success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode: AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement error:&audioSessionError];`

However "Volume Limit" doesn't allow me to make measurements predictable. And I'm wondering how can I turn off "EQ" and "Volume Limit" for my audio session programmatically? Please advise...
Cheers...

Comment: I don't think you should be able to control the Volume Limit programmatically- it is determined by the user, not the dev...

Comment: AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement should disable everything which disturbs measurements or provide sanity check. Because apple dosn't do it which is logical bug, im looking for a way around SD6 http://www.studiosixdigital.com/iphone_hardware/iphone_3gs_microphone.html "Also, in most of the later models, there is a limiter -- making SPL measurements, as well as more sophisticated measures such as Impulse Response difficult to make accurately. Again, we can disable this limiter (as of iOS 4.3), so we can work around this."

Comment: On a developer phone, go to Settings->Developer->turn EU Volume limit off.